# Using line_profiler/kernprof with mpiexec

Tags: python, profiling, mpi4py, mpiexec

I'm trying to do some line-by-line profiling of a Python program that uses `mpi4py` using the `kernprof` (https://github.com/rkern/line_profiler) profiler.

If I simply run the script with in the normal way:

```
kernprof -l -v mpi_program.py
```

everything seems to work, but course only a single instance (rank=0) of the MPI program is run.
I therefore want to run it with `mpiexec` to get more processes running, but if I run the profiler inside `mpiexec` the programs just runs and no profiling information is produced:

```
mpiexec -l kernprof -l -v mpi_program.py
```

Does anyone have any experiance with running `kernprof`on an MPI program?

Answer (score 0):

Did you manually decorate any functions? I have run kernprof with mpi4py programs and also had empty results unless I specified particular functions with @profile.